# Is there a lightweight SQL-capable database management software that doesn't try to be a server?

Tags: database, command-line, sql

I'm looking for a program that's specifically *not* an SQL server. SQL servers seem to deal with permissions, connectivity, and all that jazz.

I just want a command line program that I can give an SQL command or script file, a database file, and have it alter/query the file according to the commands issued. Nothing more, nothing less.

Here's an example of my use case

```
$ ls
database
$ sql-thing --command "SELECT MIN(Balance) FROM Users"
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org) would be just the thing. Sqlite comes as a C library and command-line utility that executes SQL statements against a database file. The software intelligently cootdinates multiple connections to one file, but doesn't use a client-server architecture.

Comment: Worth pointing out it's available cross-platform. And though being very light-weight, can deal with quite some data. For example, a small Nextcloud instance ;)

Comment: Didn't know SQLite offers a CLI, thought it was just a library. Thanks! :)